# Improper integral $\int_e^\infty \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x^2-e^p)(\ln^3{x}-1)}}$

Tags: calculus, analysis, improper-integrals

Convergence of improper integral $$\int_e^\infty \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x^2-e^p)(\ln^3{x}-1)}}$$ has to be investigated. After substitution $x=et$, I got integral $$\int_1^\infty \frac{dt}{\sqrt{(t^2-e^{p-2})(\ln^3{t}+3\ln^2{t}+3\ln{t})}}.$$ For $p<2$ integral converges, but I cannot deduce what happens for $p\geq 2$?
Any help is welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of subbing $x= e t$, try $x = e^t$.

Comment: When $p=2$, the integrand is $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x^2-e^2)(\log^2 x-1)}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x-e)(\log x-1)}} \cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x+e)(\log^2 x+\log x+1)}},$$ which behaves like $\frac{\text{constant}}{x-e}$ as $x\to e^+$ and hence the integral diverges. If $p>2$, then how do you deal with the square root of negative numbers? (I guess you don't learn how to integrate complex-valued functions in calculus.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could analyze the problem composing Taylor series from inside to outside around $x=e$.

First, rewrite
$$x^2-e^p=\left(e^2-e^p\right)+2 e (x-e)+(x-e)^2$$
Now
$$\log(x)=1+\frac{x-e}{e}-\frac{(x-e)^2}{2 e^2}+O\left((x-e)^3\right)$$ Binomial expansion
$$\log^3(x)=1+\frac{3 (x-e)}{e}+\frac{3 (x-e)^2}{2 e^2}+O\left((x-e)^3\right)$$
$$\left(x^2-e^p\right) \left(\log ^3(x)-1\right)=\left(e^2-e^p\right)+\left(5 e-3 e^{p-1}\right) (x-e)+O\left((x-e)^2\right)$$
Long division
$$\frac 1 {\left(x^2-e^p\right) \left(\log ^3(x)-1\right)}=\frac{1}{e^2-e^p}+\frac{\left(3 e^p-5 e^2\right) }{e
   \left(e^2-e^p\right)^2}(x-e)+O\left((x-e)^2\right)$$ Binomial expansion
$$\frac 1 {\sqrt{\left(x^2-e^p\right) \left(\log ^3(x)-1\right)}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{e^2-e^p}}\Bigg[1+\frac{\left(3 e^p-5 e^2\right) (x-e)}{2 e
   \left(e^2-e^p\right)}+O\left((x-e)^2\right)\Bigg]$$

So, the only case where it would diverge is $p=2$. And, if you want to stay in the real domain, because of the pre-factor, you need $e^2>e^p$ that is to say $p<2$.